# Excel formula: counting criteria within an array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm facing an Excel issue that I haven't been able to solve with any quick formulas.

I'm working with an Excel spreadsheet which contains 3 columns A:B. Column A "CODE" displays strings of repeated values, column B "CHECKS" also displays strings of repeated values and column C which should output TRUE/FALSE.

On the side column E,  I have a criteria box with 3 values, 55, 66, 77 I would be interested in knowing whether these values appear in column B for each unique strings within column A and output a TRUE if they do.

Here is an image which illustrates my example:

[image: Example]

Is there an easy way of calculating this via a formula or array formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way would be to check each criterium and then see if all are met (formula into cell C2)

```
=(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,$E$2)>0)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,$E$3)>0)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,$E$4)>0)=1
```